# Can I sync two PRTG deployments using one database?

Tags: proxy, monitoring, zabbix, prtg

I have the following scenario:
[image]

```
WS1 = Windows  **(Has Internet)**
WS2 = Windows (No Internet)
SERVERX = Linux (No Internet)
```

We want to monitor SERVERX ( get CPU usage, disk space..etc and **get alerts via email!**) I was thinking about using Zabbix OR PRTG (Monitoring tools)
But turned out Zabbix cannot be installed on Windows. and we need to get Disk space usage to be reported view email when exceeding a limit.
Please have a look at the picture to understand the challenge.

*I was thinking about the following setup:*

```
WS1 have PRTG installed
WS2 have PRTG installed 
Both WS1,WS2 share the same PRTG database (Synced)
```

Is this even possible? or do you have other solutions?

Comment: You need a Linux host for both for Zabbix Server (the one sending notifications) and Zabbix Proxy (WS2 in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Use Master Probe on WS1 and remote probe on WS2 - this way your master probe will store collected results into database and send emails since it is connected to Internet.

Remote probe is the one who is doing checks and who is constantly connected to master probe and pushes results to it.

This is standard PRTG functionality - see following page for details https://www.paessler.com/manuals/prtg/install_a_prtg_remote_probe

Comment: That's what I did eventually and it worked, thanks though!